# Mostrar um <select> ao clicar em um determinado <option>

Tags: javascript

Sou inexperiente em javascript, e gostaria de uma ajuda nesse caso:

Tenho dois selects em meu documento:

```
<select id="estado">
<option value="MG">MG</option>
<option value="SP">SP</option>
<option value="RJ">RJ</option>
<option value="RJ">BA</option>
</select>
<select id="cidade">
<option value="Belo Horizonte">Belo Horizonte</option>
<option value="Betim">Betim</option>
<option value="Contagem">Contagem</option>
</select>
```

O comportamento esperado é que, ao clicar em um option do estado, ele substitua o select de id=cidade. Acredito que document.write seja a solução, porém, o conteúdo a ser substituído deve ser levado em conta a ordem do option clicado no select id=estado e não seu value.

Por exemplo:

O primeiro option substitui o select cidade para:

```
<select id="cidade">
<option value="Sou o primeiro">Sou o primeiro</option>
</select>
```

O segundo option substitui o select cidade para:

```
<select id="cidade">
<option value="Sou o segundo">Sou o segundo</option>
</select>
```

O terceiro substitui o select cidade para:

```
<select id="cidade">
<option value="Sou o terceiro">Sou o terceiro</option>
</select>
```

O quarto substitui o select cidade para:

```
<select id="cidade">
<option value="Sou o quarto">Sou o quarto</option>
</select>
```

O problema maior é que estes valores a serem substituidos devem ter referência pela ordem no select estado, e não pelo seu value.
Ou seja, não importa o value do terceiro option do select #estado, não importa se será SP, RJ, MG ou BA, ele ao ser clicado, vai substituir o outro select com o terceiro código acima. Se clicar no segundo option, substitui pelo segundo código.

Bem é isso. Agradeço a todos que ajudarem.

Comment: Você quer substituir o `select#cidade` por inteiro ou somente o seu "Conteúdo", as `<option>`? Acho que não entendi bem a sua pergunta

Comment: Você está usando alguma lib, como `jQuery` por exemplo?

Comment: Você quer que ao selecionar um estado, no select de cidades seja carregada uma lista das respectivas a aquele estado?

Comment: @RichardDias Não estou usando bibliotecas. A idéia é que, ao clicar no primeiro option do #estado, substitua a lista #cidade pela Lista referente ao primeiro option. Ou seja, não importa os values, a substituição é fixa pela ordem do primeiro, segundo, teceiro option. Pode ser somente o conteúdo das option, ou o que for mais fácil.

Comment: Boni, neste tipo de situação, te aconselho a fazer o carregamento do segundo select com AJAX. Caso tenha alguma dúvida de como fazê-lo, apenas me diga qual tecnologia está usando no Server-Side, PHP, Ruby, C#, etc. Se for apenas uma atividade acadêmica, você pode manter listas com as cidades, e apenas recarregar o conteúdo.

Comment: @TobyMosque É uma atividade bem simples, não precisa de AJAX não. Não é preciso levar em consideração as cidades. Como falei, os códigos da primeira, segunda, teceira opção são fixos, o código do primeiro option deve aparecer independente do value que possua. E assim vai para o segundo, terceiro, etc.

Comment: A pergunta e... qual a necessidade disso? Explique-nos, quem sabe não consigamos entender melhor e ajuda-lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como esclarecido pelo Autor da pergunta, o importante aqui é a obtenção do indice do option selecionado.

segue um novo exemplo:

```js
//pre-consulta para obter os selects #master e #details
var master = document.getElementById("master");
var details = document.getElementById("details");

master.onchange = function () {
  //necessario para poder utilizar o método indexOf nos options de #master
  var options = master.querySelectorAll("option");
  options = Array.prototype.slice.call(options);
  
  //recuperando o option selecionado
  selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(options, function(option) {
      return option.selected;
  });    
  
  //recuperando o indice do option selecionado, caso não exista uma option selecionado, atribuir 0.
  var indice = 0;
  if (selected != null && selected.length == 1) 
      indice = options.indexOf(selected[0]);
  
  //caso nenhum option seja selecionado ou se o option default for selecionado, desativar #details.
  details.disabled = indice == 0;
  details.readOnly = indice == 0;    
  
  //atualizando os valores de #details.
  details.innerHTML = '';
  if (indice != 0) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = "Indice Selecionado: " + indice;        
    details.appendChild(option);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="master" >Master: </label>
  <select id="master" >
    <option>Selecione um Valor</option>
    <option>Primeiro</option>
    <option>Segundo</option>
    <option>Terceiro</option>
    <option>Quarto</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="details" >Details: </label>
  <select id="details" >
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não é isso o que queria. Não sei se expressei direito, mas esqueça as cidades. A questão é a seguinte: não importa o value do option que seja escolhido, se for o primeiro option, mostra no outro select uma lista de options pré-definida, independente se é MG ou CE. Se for o segundo option, aí mostrará outro select com outra lista. O que diferencia as listas de options geradas não é o value, e sim a ordem que estão os options do primeiro select.

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado.